# Glob patterns for file matching in PHP - Get directory contents which do not start with a string group

Tags: php, glob

## How can I ignore all images that begin with the string 'blogCover'?

*At first I did not exclude a picture for the test*

**all pictures in img directory:**

```php
$imgDir = 'img';
$imgs = glob($imgDir.'/*{.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE); //all images!
echo'<pre>'; print_r($imgs); echo'</pre>';
```

result:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => img/blogCover-large.jpg
    [1] => img/blogCover-large_2x.jpg
    [2] => img/blogCover-medium.jpg
    [3] => img/blogCover-medium_2x.jpg
    [4] => img/blogCover-small.jpg
    [5] => img/blogCover-small_2x.jpg
    [6] => img/boddy-large.jpg
    [7] => img/boddy-large_2x.jpg
    [8] => img/boddy-medium.jpg
    [9] => img/boddy-medium_2x.jpg
    [10] => img/boddy-small.jpg
    [11] => img/boddy-small_2x.jpg
    [12] => img/face-large.jpg
    [13] => img/face-large_2x.jpg
    [14] => img/face-medium.jpg
    [15] => img/face-medium_2x.jpg
    [16] => img/face-small.jpg
    [17] => img/face-small_2x.jpg
    [18] => img/hand-large.jpg
    [19] => img/hand-large_2x.jpg
    [20] => img/hand-medium.jpg
    [21] => img/hand-medium_2x.jpg
    [22] => img/hand-small.jpg
    [23] => img/hand-small_2x.jpg
    [24] => img/head-large.jpg
    [25] => img/head-large_2x.jpg
    [26] => img/head-medium.jpg
    [27] => img/head-medium_2x.jpg
    [28] => img/head-small.jpg
    [29] => img/head-small_2x.jpg
)
```

**my goal:** Ignore all images that begin with the string 'blogCover'

```php
$imgDir = 'img';
$imgs = glob($imgDir.'/*{[!blogCover*].jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
echo'<pre>'; print_r($imgs); echo'</pre>';
```

**unexpected result:**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => img/blogCover-large_2x.jpg
    [1] => img/blogCover-medium.jpg
    [2] => img/blogCover-medium_2x.jpg
    [3] => img/blogCover-small_2x.jpg
    [4] => img/boddy-large_2x.jpg
    [5] => img/boddy-medium.jpg
    [6] => img/boddy-medium_2x.jpg
    [7] => img/boddy-small_2x.jpg
    [8] => img/face-large_2x.jpg
    [9] => img/face-medium.jpg
    [10] => img/face-medium_2x.jpg
    [11] => img/face-small_2x.jpg
    [12] => img/hand-large_2x.jpg
    [13] => img/hand-medium.jpg
    [14] => img/hand-medium_2x.jpg
    [15] => img/hand-small_2x.jpg
    [16] => img/head-large_2x.jpg
    [17] => img/head-medium.jpg
    [18] => img/head-medium_2x.jpg
    [19] => img/head-small_2x.jpg
)
```

> all '* -large.jpg', '* -small.jpg' images are missing

**expected result:**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => img/boddy-large.jpg
    [1] => img/boddy-large_2x.jpg
    [2] => img/boddy-medium.jpg
    [3] => img/boddy-medium_2x.jpg
    [4] => img/boddy-small.jpg
    [5] => img/boddy-small_2x.jpg
    [6] => img/face-large.jpg
    [7] => img/face-large_2x.jpg
    [8] => img/face-medium.jpg
    [9] => img/face-medium_2x.jpg
    [10] => img/face-small.jpg
    [11] => img/face-small_2x.jpg
    [12] => img/hand-large.jpg
    [13] => img/hand-large_2x.jpg
    [14] => img/hand-medium.jpg
    [15] => img/hand-medium_2x.jpg
    [16] => img/hand-small.jpg
    [17] => img/hand-small_2x.jpg
    [18] => img/head-large.jpg
    [19] => img/head-large_2x.jpg
    [20] => img/head-medium.jpg
    [21] => img/head-medium_2x.jpg
    [22] => img/head-small.jpg
    [23] => img/head-small_2x.jpg
)
```

> **I expect to ignore these pictures:**

- blogCover-large.jpg
- blogCover-large_2x.jpg
- blogCover-medium.jpg
- blogCover-medium_2x.jpg
- blogCover-small.jpg
- blogCover-small_2x.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is:

```
$imgs = glob($imgDir.'/[^blogCover]*.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: that does not work. the result is: empty array.! and with asterisk after slash (glob($imgDir.'/*[^blogCover]*.jpg', GLOB_BRACE);) that does not work too!